# Laravel 5: Form fields not in model

Tags: forms, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5

I have a model with a field called `map_zips` and inside that field, I would like to store up to 5 zip codes, comma separated.

I would like to have five different form fields that before getting stored in the database model, I concatenate the values together and store them in the DB in the single column.

How can I create multiple form fields in a view, validate said form fields, perform what needs to be done on said form fields, store them?  Beyond that, I think I will also need to split them up when loading up the edit/update page as well.

I guess the simplest way would be to create 5 different columns, one for each zip, but I'd like to learn how to do this to help extend my limited knowledge of Laravel.

In my `ReportsController.php` my current store method looks like this:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, $this->rules);
    $user                     = Auth::user();
    $report                   = $request->all();
    $report['user_id']        = $user->id;
    Report::create($report);
    return redirect('/reports')->with('status', 'Report created');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if i undertand you question but you can try this:

if you want 5 input fields in your view you can try this, you will see error messages from you validation and a returned message to confirm that the value was stored propperly

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <div>{{ $error }}</div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
@if(session()->has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session()->get('message') }}
    </div>
@endif  
<form action="{{ route("route_to_store_function") }}" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="zip1">
    <input type="text" name="zip2">
    <input type="text" name="zip3">
    <input type="text" name="zip4">
    <input type="text" name="zip5">
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

then in your store function, concatenate the fields, save the report and return with a message to the previous page:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'zip1' => 'required',// you can add more validations here
        'zip2' => 'required',
        'zip3' => 'required',
        'zip4' => 'required',
        'zip5' => 'required',
    ]);

    $report = new Report();
    $report->map_zips = $request->zip1.",".$request->zip2.",".$request->zip3.",".$request->zip4.",".$request->zip5;
    $report->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'The report has been stored succesfully');
}
```

Then when you want to edit the report you can try this:

```
public function edit($id) {
    $report = Report::find($id)

    $zipCodes = explode(",", $report->map_zips);
    return view('edit_report_view', compact("report", "zipCodes"));
}
```

And in you edit view:

```
<form action="{{ route("route_to_update") }}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $report->id }}">
    <input type="text" name="zip1" value="{{ $zipCodes[0] }}">
    <input type="text" name="zip2" value="{{ $zipCodes[1] }}">
    <input type="text" name="zip3" value="{{ $zipCodes[2] }}">
    <input type="text" name="zip4" value="{{ $zipCodes[3] }}">
    <input type="text" name="zip5" value="{{ $zipCodes[4] }}">
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```